# Changing PHP-GD version

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, drupal, gd, yum

I wanted to change the PHP-GD version on my AWS stack as my Drupal installer told me it was missing. I installed php-gd55 first, but on realizing it was not the correct package, I decided to change it to php-gd package. However, I am running into dependency issues when I am trying to install php-gd after removing php-gd55 and all its leaf extensions
[image]

It appears that the conflicting packages were installed when I installed php-gd55 extension but were not removed when I removed it with its leaf packages.